# Using a 120W inverter with a 180W brick

Tags: power-supply

For some testing at my company, we attach the product to a small plane and collect data with a laptop. The product itself is run off a small motorcycle battery and, last time we flew, our laptop battery died. I checked out the specs on the power supply and it was listed as 180W.

Our pilot happens to have a 120W (with the correct output voltage) inverter for a 12V DC plug in the cockpit. If we were to use that and plug the laptop into it, would that just be 2/3 of the current draw and the charging would be slower? If, for whatever reason, my laptop is using the full power normally supplied, draining at 1/3 the normal speed would be awesome if it tripled my battery life.

I found inverters with 200+W ratings online, but they suggest only hooking up directly to a battery because plugs often have fuses at 15A or less. Since the only one up there is the motorcycle battery, it would have to be that. However, I'm hesitant to use that battery because it's rated at 12 Ah, which 12/15 = 40 minutes to drain just powering the laptop.

Comment: "would that just be 2/3 of the current draw and the charging would be slower" No you will blow a fuse somewhere.

Comment: I think you would have to test that inverter with the laptop : connect it when the laptop battery is fully charged and see how it behaves - will it give the extended life? But, I think that if you connect the laptop to the inverter with the battery low or half-charged it may draw more than the inverter can produce and shut itself down. Test it and see, but On The Ground....

Comment: But if you fully charge your laptop before using the inverter and put your laptop in power saving mode, you can probably get away with ~50W typically but do ask the pilot what happens if you blow a fuse mid air. Also pulling 15A continuously from a 12Ah battery till it's empty sounds sketchy, too, so also do check the rating of the battery, too.

Comment: shlady - Too many points for me to try to reply to all. But FYI as *user3528438* said, your battery life calculation is problematic. Pulling 15A from "*a small motorcycle battery*" ... "*rated at 12 Ah, which 12/15 = 40 minutes to drain just powering the laptop.*" No. (a) 180W o/p would require > 15A (not 100% efficient). (b) Check the datasheet from your specific battery, but from an industry standard 12Ah SLA battery, you *might* get ~15 mins assuming 90% efficient inverter with 10.5V cut-off voltage. Typical SLA battery capacity rated (advertised) at 12Ah does **not** mean 12A for 1 hr.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot of interesting things in here, so I'll try my best to hit them all.

1) Just because the laptop power supply is rated at 180W doesn't mean the laptop will draw 180W.  If the laptop starts off fully charged, its actual power draw should be quite a bit less (after all, you can use the laptop and charge it simultaneously, right?)  So you should measure how much power the laptop ACTUALLY draws.  You can also adjust settings on the laptop to minimize power draw (laptops have power save modes, but you'll need to specifically turn them on since the laptop thinks it's plugged in and thus doesn't care about power usage)

2) If you do try to draw a full 180W from an inverter rated to 120W, you're not going to get 120W.  As mentioned in the comments, you will either blow a fuse or brown out the circuit.  That's why you need to know the true power draw of the laptop.  As long as the laptop never draws more than 120W, you should be able to plug in using the inverter just fine.

3) Getting a higher-rated inverter isn't likely to help you because the pilot has probably already sized the 120W inverter based on the capacity of his 12V plug.  But, doesn't hurt to ask.

4) I'm not going to go into much detail on the motorcycle battery since I think in your case the right answer is to run off the 120W aircraft power.  But if you do go the battery route, I strongly recommend measuring its lifetime at the actual power draw of your product + laptop.  As SamGibson pointed out (see comments), listed battery capacities are generally overly optimistic in realistic operating conditions.  I'm assuming flight time is expensive, so it's worth the time on the ground to figure out exactly how much operating time you'll have.  The battery datasheet should give you lifetime vs discharge current, but that will change depending on how old the battery is and other factors - the best bet is to measure it yourself.